# ocmod extension working in op2.0 but vqmod stop automatically

Tags: opencart2.x

I have try ocmod extensions installing opencart 2.0 now onwards ocmod extensions are working well but vqmod used already installed extension stopped. i mean not working. if i clear or disable ocmod exntesion then vqmods all pluging working.

Comment: please give me suggestions. i have still problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we have remove vqcache or give them permission to re create then this problem will be resolving.

if further still issue then problem with extension try other or contact extension developer.